# How can I send email using a different domain+IP for some senders?

Tags: email, joomla, cpanel, whm

We send a newsletter from our Joomla 3 (with WHM and cPanel) site by email using Acymailing. We've been using a fixed IP address for this for about 10 years, have an excellent reputation on postmaster.google.com, validity.com, etc., always have close to zero user-reported spam and remove users who do so or we get bounced emails from to keep our lists clean, are on all available Feedback Loops, and are not on any block lists per checks using mxtoolbox, proofpoint.com, etc.

Despite that, once every year or 2 we get on a block list and we fill in a remediation form and get taken off it again which usually takes from 1 to 4 days. Not a big deal for the newsletter but it means we can't reach some of our customers during the period while we're blocked and that can be a big deal.

It happened again recently at an inopportune time and so we'd like to change things so we'll be able to continue sending our newsletter from our existing domain+IP address since we've built up that reputation for 10 years, but also be able to send non-newsletter email to individual customers or small groups of people from a different domain+IP address so we can reach them even during those small periods where our other domain+IP is blocked.

I think we need both the domain and IP to be different, rather than just the IP, as some block lists can be based on domain name rather than IP address (or so google tells me).

The tricky part is that we have scenarios where we (I think) need to be able to use the same web site for both types of email. For example, we use Acymailing to create our newsletter and the process we currently go through is (where old.com represents our current domain+IP and new.com some new domain+IP, could be google.com or a new site):

- We create a draft email on old.com.
- We send the draft from our_address@old.com to customer@gmail.com to review and approve the draft.
- After it's approved we add it to the Acymailing queue.
- At the scheduled day/time Acymailing sends it to our subscribers from our_address@old.com

If we introduce a new domain+IP for sending everything except the approved newsletter then the process becomes:

- We create a draft email on old.com.
- We send the draft from our_address@**new**.com to customer@gmail.com to review and approve the draft.
- After it's approved we add it to the Acymailing queue.
- At the scheduled day/time Acymailing sends it to our subscribers from our_address@old.com

Note that we need the email content to exist on 1 site but be able to send emails about it from 2 different domain+IPs. There are other scenarios where we need this functionality too.

Also, emails using the new domain+IP won't ONLY be sent from the site using Acymailing, they'll also be sent directly from Webmail or Thunderbird.

So - can we do anything with our 1 Joomla site to set something up in Joomla, cPanel, WHM or elsewhere to let us use a different domain+IP to send email from based on the "From" email address we specify in the email we create or something else?

Obviously we also need to be able to receive emails sent to the new address and we don't want anything about this conflicting with our existing DKIM, DNS, etc. settings.

I've read, e.g. at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10911/2-domains-2-templates-one-cms-with-same-content, about various extensions for letting multiple domains share a database but I'm very much a naive Joomla user and that all sounds pretty daunting and hopefully is overkill for what we need.

Comment: @blackgreen why did you delete the one answer that was posted? Is it wrong or is there some other issue?